# Model-View-Controller: when should changes to the view be determined by the controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

Model-View-Controller seems to allow two types of changes to the view:

1. Whenever the model changes, the view receives a change notification so it can update its visual representation accordingly.
2. The controller is given direct access to the view's API for the purposes of "View Selection".

What exactly is "View Selection", and under what circumstances should the controller be making changes to the view rather than having the view make its own changes based only on the model?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that you may find useful.

[Modified MVC Pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html)

The authors presented a MVC flow, in which the Model sending notifications to Controller (not View, as in the traditional way). Hence, the controller mediates the flow of data between model and view objects in both directions. As they said

> This design helps to more completely decouple the model from the view. In this case, the controller can dictate the model properties that it expects to find in one or more models registered with the controller. In addition, it can also provide the methods that effect the model's property changes for one or more views that are registered with it

... which is the answer to your question about what is View Selection. It is basically just that the application has a series of Views that are related or updated according to a single change in the Model. And Controller will decide which set of Views need to be updated and/collaborated to get the work done (information from one View is not enough)

Answer (score 0):

Being used at web apllication in MVC there is not event notification mechanism, unlike MVVM your view won't notify view as it changes. But its is controller action that create and pass model as a part of redering views.